# Condition for current time greater than or equal to from time and current time less than or equal to time in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

Condition not working because using TO_CHAR(),but how to extract time? following is my query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM SUPPLY_TIMING
 WHERE TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH:Mi') >= TO_CHAR (FROM_TIME, 'HH:Mi')
       AND TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH:Mi') <= TO_CHAR (TO_TIME, 'HH:Mi')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are interested only in the time but not in the date part. Assuming data type of `FROM_TIME` and `TO_TIME` are `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` you can do this:

```
select *
FROM SUPPLY_TIMING
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSDATE) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SYSDATE)/60 
   BETWEEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM FROM_TIME) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM FROM_TIME)/60
       AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TO_TIME) + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIME)/60
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, my guess is that your format mask is what's causing the problem. The `HH` component will give you the hours in twelve hour format, so 1pm will be returned as `01`, I think if you used `HH24` instead, you would get `13`, making the string comparison work as intended:

```
SELECT *
FROM SUPPLY_TIMING
WHERE TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:Mi') >= TO_CHAR (FROM_TIME, 'HH24:Mi')
AND TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'HH24:Mi') <= TO_CHAR (TO_TIME, 'HH24:Mi')
```